# "$_.extension -eq" not working as intended?

Tags: powershell

I tried to write a small script to automate the creation of playlists (m3u) for dozens of folders/subfolders of mp3/mp4 files, while omitting various other misc files therein. I know very little about Powershell but managed to piece together something that almost works. The only blip is that when I use "$_.extension -eq", it doesn't seem to work, or at least I'm not using it right. If I use it to match log/txt files in a temp folder for example, it works, but not in this instance. Here is the code -

```
$pathname = read-host "Enter path"
$root = Get-ChildItem $pathname | ? {$_.PSIsContainer}
$rootpath = $pathname.substring(0,2)
Set-Location $rootpath
Set-Location $pathname
foreach($folder in $root) {
Set-Location $folder
foreach($file in $folder) {
$txtfile =".m3u"
$files = gci | Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".mp3" -or ".mp4"}
$count = $files.count
if($count -ge 2){
$txtfile = "_" + $folder.name + $txtfile
Add-Content $txtFile $files
}  
}
if(test-path $txtFile){
Add-Content $txtFile `r
}
Set-Location $pathname
}
```

I have tried several variations like swapping "-match" for "-eq" but no luck. incidentally, if I omit the "-or ".mp4"" from the parentheses then it works fine, but I need it to match both, and only both mp3/mp4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as you complain about extension, let's start with it. Presumably there is a bug in the code; this expression/syntax is technically valid:

```
$_.extension -eq ".mp3" -or ".mp4"
```

But apparently the intent was:

```
$_.extension -eq ".mp3" -or $_.extension -eq ".mp4"
```

Try the corrected expression at first.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to add this as a shortcut option:

```
gci | Where-Object {".mp3",".mp4" -eq $_.extension}
```

Comment: I think operator `-contains`  would be better: it gets not confusing Boolean (it’s not the case for the `-eq` in the example) and presumably it should be more effective (it stops at the first found item). But the idea itself is good, extensions may be defined as an array `$extensions ` then we can do this simple Boolean check: `$extensions -contains $_.extension`.

Comment: -eq also supports arrays, so there is no difference that I can think of.

Comment: Difference is subtle but it exists. 1) `-eq` returns a string in your example, if it exists; in general case it returns array of matched items. It’s not Boolean at all. 2) By definition `-eq` has to scan *all* the items even if one has been already found. All in all: `-eq` looks heavier for this task than `-contains`.

Comment: Here is example of real difference: try this: `if ('', 'xxx' -eq '') { 'found' } else { 'not found' }` and this `if ('', 'xxx' -contains '') { 'found' } else { 'not found' }`. Results are different.

Comment: Yes, there is some performance difference if you have a large collection (which is not the case here).